# Unsupervised anomaly detection on multivariate time series

Tags: time-series, correlation, multivariate-analysis, anomaly-detection, prophet

Me and my team face the next use case:

Our data consists of 3 numerical signals,
Which are collected every 10 minutes.
Example:

[image]

Our main goal is to build an anomaly detection algorithm.
Our work till now:

1. We tried to use VAR model. training the model every 10 minutes and predicting one step ahead.
   The issue with this approach is that our data does have some daily seasonality, and looking only the values itself yields many false positives. In our system if the values are anomalous, but the seasonality, or we can call it the "wave" itself, is similar to previous days at the same time, we will not consider it as anomaly.
2. our next approach was to try and use Fourier transformation to filter the "noise" out of each of the 3 signals, and then to use periodogram to find if there are different peaks between daily signals.
   The issue with this approach is that even though our data has seasonality, there are unexpected hills and peaks every day, so the periodogram's were pretty much different between each day.
3. For our next approach, we decided to use fbprophet 2,which uses NN. We decided to look at each of the signal by itself. we run the prophet prediction, we captures the "behavior" of the signal pretty well ( in terms of the wave, not the absolute values ), and we use 2 measures:
4. Pearson correlation between the predicted values the the true values - which will give us information about how good the vectors are correlated and if the ratio was the same.
5. we take the average absolute difference between predicted and true vector.

The issue with this approach is that we basically dealing again with one dimensional time series, and do not use the information within the  "behavior" of the 3 signals together - for example and anomaly can be then signal x drops and signal y rises at the same time.

Can you please give your opinion regarding our work till now,
And advice about other approaches you are familiar with?

Thanks,

Arkady

Comment: Anomalies are deviations from the modelled/theoretic/hypothesized values. What model are you considering? Or are you trying to detect 'extreme' values instead of anomalies? My advice is that you describe very well what you mean by anomaly before attacking it with several arbitrary algorithms.

Comment: Hi, In our case anomaly would be extreme values that continues for some period of time, or regular values with sudden trend: deacreasing/increasing line, maybe exponential decrease. maybe it will be more accurate to say we are more interested in  anomalous trend instead of values.